# phpmailer Invalid Address Error

Tags: php, phpmailer

Code:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  

    var_dump($email);
        $data =  explode(',', $_POST['data']);

      mailImages($data);

    }


    function mailImages($data){
        require_once "../PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php";

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

        try {
          $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
          $mail->AddReplyTo('kasper.lassner@peterwolf.agency', 'Colegio Suizo de México');
         // $mail->AddAddress('******@****.agency','K L');
          //$mail->AddAddress('"'.$email.'"','');
           $mail->AddAddress($email,'test');
          $mail->SetFrom('*******@********.agency', 'Colegio Suizo de México');
          $mail->Subject = 'CSM Fotos';
          $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
          $mail->MsgHTML('Test message');

          foreach($data as $image){
             $mail->AddAttachment(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.str_replace(' ','',$image));
          }


          $mail->Send();
          echo 'OK';
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
          //echo $e->errorMessage();
          echo $mail->ErrorInfo; 

        } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo 'NO';//Boring error messages from anything else!
        }
    }
    ?>
```

So my problem is the following: I get an "Invalid Address:"" Error. When I comment this line:

```
$mail->AddAddress($email,'test');
```

And uncomment this line:

```
$mail->AddAddress('******@****.agency','K L');
```

Passing a string value works. So the problem clearly is that the `$email` variable somehow isn't accepted. The var_dump outputs this: `"string(24) "*******@****.com"` so it is a string.

I've searched in already existing answers and couldn't find that specific issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't help that you have based your code on an obsolete example and are using a really old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: ^^ Right.  The variable `$email` does not appear to be in scope in the `mailImages()` function.  Only `$data` was passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Synchro: I downloaded this yesterday from the phpmailer website. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: thanks Michael, I give the correct answer melpomene because I can't vote for a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is explained in http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

By default, every variable you use in a function is implicitly local to that function. The `$email` in `mailImages` is unrelated to the `$email` outside. Because the variable is not set, it causes the "Invalid Address" error.

You can fix this by either adding another function parameter:

```
function mailImages($data, $email) { ... }

// call as
mailImages($data, $email);
```

or by explicitly marking `$email` as global:

```
function mailImages($data) {
    global $email;
    ...
}
```